# WordPress and TTFB (time to first byte) stats

Tags: performance, hosting

I am currently working with a client that last time I checked was averaging 8-9 SECONDS for their TTFB (time to first byte). So as you can imagine they are looking at a 12-14 seconds page load time. I have done some research on how the WordPress architecture could affect the TTFB and I'm a little confused.

I guess my main question is could WordPress be responsible for such a high TTFB or does that smell more like a hosting/hardware issue? Or could WordPress return those types of delays if configured incorrectly?

Any information would be helpful at this point.

Comment: Try to set up a fresh WordPress on that server and check TTFB. Then you'll know. If TTFB still is bad then this is a server-specific issue. If not, then you'll know that something on your client's WordPress is wrong. Too much plugins, buggy custom code, missing resources, could have many reasons. Which then makes this question too broad I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, load times are such a broad question it's not possible for others to speculate. There are various page speed tools that can help you better understand whether it's the server or the application, and there are query monitor plugins for WP you can use to determine what part of the application may be slowing things down. Really, only installing the application on a different server will tell you for certain whether it's a problem with the hosting stack or not, but you can also look into optimizing the WP database and deactivating plugins and themes to manually try to isolate what is causing the slowdown.